# pyenv: how to install python dynamic/shared library

Tags: python, installation, pyenv, dynamic-library

When I compile python from source manually (with `--enable-shared`), I get a dynamic library in the `lib` directory. For example:

```bash
$ ls $PYTHON_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/lib
libpython3.9.so  libpython3.9.so.1.0  libpython3.so  pkgconfig  python3.9
```

However, when I install python using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), I only get a static library:

```bash
$ ls .../pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib
libpython3.9.a  pkgconfig  python3.9
```

How can I force `pyenv` to install Python dynamic library? What command I should run instead of

```bash
$ pyenv install --verbose 3.9.13
```

(I need to compile a software project which requires linking with python dynamic library)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 11):

I have found a [solution](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/plugins/python-build/README.md#building-with---enable-shared):

```bash
$ env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install --verbose 3.9.13
```